# Laravel Query builter to JSON as eloquent

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm using laravel with query builder.

Is there a way to transform a query builder result into json respecting the child elements and not creating a parse manually ?

I mean, transform this:

```
id  customer  product_id product
1   Will      1          Mouse
1   Will      2          Keyboard
```

into this:

```
{
  customer: { 
    id: 1,
    customer: will,
    product: [{
      id: 1,
      product: Mouse
    },{
      id: 2,
      product: Keyboard
    }]
}
```

I have lots of code using eloquent today that needs to migrate to query builder. If I could generate a json after querying, it would salve a LOT of work changing all the other methods and views.

Comment: QueryBuilder (and Eloquent) has a `->toJson()` method, but that will return the json results in the same structure as the table, and if using Eloquent, will return any retrieved child classes in the json. However, if your table is in the first format, and you want the second, you'll need to create it yourself or create a [JSON Resource class](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping) to do it for you

Answer (score -1):

```
id  customer  product_id product
1   Will      1          Mouse
1   Will      2          Keyboard
```

Firstly, should say it looks like a bad way to keep data, wrong-structured.

Secondly, Ok, let it be. Then laravel-way of solving your problem contains of 2 things:

1. Query to get data
2. Transforming data, as for me [Laravel Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#concept-overview) is exactly what u need.

Now, lets look closer:

1. Query, as topic says, using Query Builder.

To improve perfomance and using only one query will take customer and all his products using mysql function [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

To get all customers:

```php
$customers = DB::table('customers')
        ->select(
            'id', 'customer', 
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(product_id, '|', product) as products)
        )
        ->groupBy('id', 'customer')
        ->get();
```

To get only one customer:

```php
$customer = DB::table('customers')
        ->select(
            'id', 'customer', 
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(product_id, '|', product) as products)
        )
        ->groupBy('id', 'customer')
        ->first();
```

2. Resource.

Create it with artisan command: `php artisan make:resource CustomerResource`.

It will place a new file in dir `app/Http/Resources`. It contains a class CustomerResource with one method - toArray() and only thing we should do is update it to look like you need:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'customer' => [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'customer' => $this->customer,
            'product' => $this->getProducts(),
        ]
    ];
}

private function getProducts(): array
{
    $products = [];
    // $this->products is string like '1|Product1,2|Product2'
    // which was created by GROUP_CONCAT function, see higher
    foreach (explode(',', $this->products) as $product) {
        $product = explode('|', $product);
        $products[] = [
            'id' => $product[0],
            'product' => $product[1]
        ]; 
    }
    
    return $products;
}
```

And only thing left is using those resource:

```
// a lot of customers was taken:
$customers = CustomerResource::collect($customers)->toJson();

//single customer:
$customer = (new CustomerResource($customer))->toJson();
```

Comment: Not your down-voter, but please consider improving your answer. As written, it looks to be a "a code-dump" answer, one that is mostly code with very little to no explanation, which is not ideal. Instead, consider adding text to your answer, a paragraph or two, that explains why you are suggesting the code that you're posting and how your suggested changes will solve the original question. Without this, your answer will not likely be helpful to future visitors, which is after all, the main purpose of this site.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really get what you're trying to do here

but for the start why did you had the product column if you had the product_id column? since you could just check the product name by the table relation ship

and why do you have the same id for customer id, you can't make an id get duplicated like that

but to make a json like that, you could try this :

```
$customers = Customer::where("customer", "Will")->get();

$product = [];

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $json = [
        'id' => $customer->product_id,
        'product' => $customer->product
    ];

    $product[] = $json;
}

$data = [
    'id' => $customers->id,
    'customer' => $customers->customer,
    'product' => $product
];
```

but I advise you to rework your database first maybe into something like this :

customer Table
| Fields | Type |
| :----- | :--- |
| id | Primary Key |
| customer | Varchar |
| product_id | Foreign Key |

product Table
| Fields | Type |
| :----- | :--- |
| id | Primary Key |
| product | Varchar |